# any time a negative number on site, color it red

Tags: javascript, colors

Thinking there's probably some javascript out there that achieves this, but everything I've found thus far seems to be very conditional. I'm trying to figure out something across my entire site that anytime there's a negative number like -30, it's always displayed in red. These values will be scraped data outputs via php. So anytime on my html page, if there's a displayed text value that's a negative, it's turned red, that's what I'm trying to do.

Not sure if this is enough details, but basically that php is outputting data like: -30%. I have a xhtml file referencing many php files scraping and outputting values and numbers. I'm trying to find a way to put some script into my xhtml file that says: if value on this page ANYWHERE is less than 0, color red. Etc

Anyone know of some good examples of this?

My test coding is this:

xml:

```
<p><font color="grey">All time high</font></p>
<?php include 'ref3.php';?>
<?php include 'alltimenasfullnumber.php';?>

  <p><font color="grey">Yearly growth</font></p>
   <?php include 'nasyearlygrowth.php';?>
```

php ref:

```
<?php 

 $doc = new DOMDocument;

// foriegn stocks
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


 $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
  $doc->recover = true;

 $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.money.cnn.com/data/markets/');

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

  $query = "//a[@class='world-market']";

  $entries = $xpath->query($query);
 foreach ($entries as $entry) {
 echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to wrap each result on your xhtml page into a distinctive tag (pre, in my example).
Here there is my code, hope this will help you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .redFont {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redText() {
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')
            for(i=0; i< elements.length; i++)
            {
                if(elements[i].innerHTML < 0) {
                   elements[i].classList.add('redFont');
                };
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
      <font color="grey">Yearly growth</font>
    </p>
    <pre><?php echo 30; ?></pre>
    <pre><?php echo -12; ?></pre>
    <pre><?php echo 15; ?></pre>
    <script>redText();</script>
</body>
```

Bye, 
Laura

Comment: Hey Laura, I really appreciate the working example! I can definitely make that work around what I'm doing. You've been super helpful thanks.

Comment: Actually doing further testing, it seems the php ref outputs are responding correctly, and always being colored red. Wonder if there's an alternative to pre. I was wrapping the php ref with pre

Comment: Hey Wilson, I'm guessing what is happening:
PHP, which is a server-side language, just respond after the DOM is parsed. So, comparing a null number to >0 in javascript, will be always true, than red.
That's why the error occurs.
Adding this code to your PHP should prevent this.

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'jsFirstfunction();',
     '</script>'
;

Comment under this if you need further explanation :)